# onClick call component with props

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Following is Navigation link with onclick event. I couldn't figure out how to call ItemModal component when navigation with onclick event is called. I have tried with following code, it's not working.

```
 <strong  onClick={() => <ItemModal modal={true} isAuthenticated={true} />}>  Add Item </strong>
```

Below is ItemModal components with reactstrap modal to add new items.

ItemModal.js

```
     import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Button,
  Modal,
  ModalHeader,
  ModalBody,
  Form,
  FormGroup,
  Label,
  Input,
} from "reactstrap";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { addItem } from "../actions/itemActions";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class ItemModal extends Component {
  state = {
    modal: false,
    name: "",
  };

  static propTypes = {
    isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool,
  };

  toggle = () => {
    this.setState({
      modal: !this.state.modal,
    });
  };

  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newItem = {
      name: this.state.name,
    };

    // Add item via addItem action
    this.props.addItem(newItem);

    //Close Modal
    this.toggle();
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.isAuthenticated ? (
          <Button
            color="dark"
            style={{ marginBottom: "2rem" }}
            onClick={this.toggle}
          >
            Add Item
          </Button>
        ) : (
          <h4 className="mb-3 ml-4"> Please log in to manage items</h4>
        )}

        <Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggle}>
          <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}> Add to Shopping List</ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>
            <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
              <FormGroup>
                <Label for="item">Item</Label>
                <Input
                  type="text"
                  name="name"
                  id="item"
                  placeholder="Add shopping item"
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                />
                <Button color="dark" style={{ marginTop: "2rem" }} block>
                  Add Item
                </Button>
              </FormGroup>
            </Form>
          </ModalBody>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  item: state.item,
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { addItem })(ItemModal);
```

How I can call component on click so that reactstrap model (ItemModal) is opened?

Comment: Returning JSX from an event handler won't render it in the DOM. Your `onclick` should set a state variable, which in turn will render the JSX in the `render` method.

Comment: Thank you lux, I have added `{this.state.clicked ? <ItemModal modal={true} toggle={true} isAuthenticated={true}/>: null}`. It does render ItemModal on first click but doesn't render on the following click. Please help me